# Rename Info.plist in compiled Storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

Is it possible to rename the Info.plist files that are created for compiled storyboards? We are having an issue with uploading IPA files to our MDM solution when there is more than one Info.plist present in the IPA file. Until they can resolve the issue on their end, the recommended solution is to rename the Info.plist files created in the compiled storyboards. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change Protect settings->target->build settings->Packaging->Info.plist file

Comment: This is already set to MyApp-Info.plist and Info.plist is created correctly for it after creating the IPA. However, when Xcode compiles the storyboards that are in the app, it generates an Info.plist file for each. These are the Info.plist files that are causing the issue.